# Reverse for 'users_index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'ip': u'192.168.1.3'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'panel/users/$']

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create href with GET parameters for the view:

```
<a href="{% url 'panel:users_index' ip=ip_entry.ip %}">
                                            {{ ip_entry.ip }}
                                        </a>
```

And Django says that

```
Reverse for 'users_index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'ip': u'192.168.1.3'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'panel/users/$']
```

But I have another template near this, and there is this code (and it works, renders to /users/?page=2&query=someuser):

```
 <a href="{% url 'panel:users_index' page=users.next_page_number query=query %}">...</a>
```

My urls.py:

```
....
url(r'^users/$', view=UsersView.as_view(), name='users_index'),
url(r'^users/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', view=UsersView.as_view(), name='users_user'),
...
```

Comment: Your url `users_index` doesn't take any parameters, you can't pass arbitrary parameters to it. Are you sure your second example works?

Comment: @ShangWang, yes, I'm sure, I've tested this :) It renders into "query" parameters, not "path" parameters: /users/?query=123

Comment: I think you are confused of what the parameters are. The query in `/users/?query=123` is not the `query` you passed in in your second example. The `query=query` is to match your variable name in your url definition, like your second url `<user_id>`. Please look at the doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined any param in `user_index` url:

```
url(r'^users/$', view=UsersView.as_view(), name='users_index'),
```

It should be:

```
url(r'^users/(?P<ip>[\w.]+)$', view=UsersView.as_view(), name='users_index'),
```

If you want to use a GET query param, you could try:

```
<a href="{% url 'panel:users_index' %}?ip={{ip_entry.ip}}"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need simple query parameters (/users/?ip=127.0.0.1), not /users/127.0.0.1/